# How do I get the full output filename of youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

Often, youtube titles have special characters that are not being saved to a file, like

```
Hello!:\\Test/
```

How do I get the full path the file is saved to?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the full path to the exported directory, this is achieved/changed by selecting the cog icon at the bottom of the main `DL-YoUTUBE` screen and taking note of the `Export Directory`

[image]

Comment: I am talking about cli output/input not a gui